# Unable to connect to Cockpit via SSH: "A compatible version of Cockpit is not installed on..." due to "spawning remote bridge failed with 0 status"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, cockpit

I'm using **Cockpit 202.1-1** amd64 locally (latest of Ubuntu Oean today) to 2 **Debian 10** servers. One works but the new fresh one doesn't, and I can't figure out why.

- I use the default "debian" user with an rsa key instead of a password. This key is added to my "Authentications" in Cockpit and unlocked. It's the same key for the 2 servers and I'm able to connect via **bash/ssh without any problem**.
- I restarted the service, rebooted the machines (local and server), without success
- On the "unable to connect server", I also **created another user to test Cockpit-WS** (as I needed a password to login) and **it works like a charm**.
- With Debian 10, Cockpit 188 is available from the main repo and 217 from the **backports** so I **enabled** them and **updated Cockpit** but **the problem remains**
- In the **server logs, no entry** speaks about **cockpit-bridge** or **cockpit-ssh**
- To make another test I synced my new user **between my two servers** (One has Cockpit 217 from backports and the other one still has the 188 one). Surprisingly, **it worked in both directions** which made me deduce that the the **problem comes from my local Cockpit**. So I greped the logs and got something interesting: `cockpit-ssh XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: spawning remote bridge failed with 0 status`
- But there is nothing about it on Google: https://www.google.com/search?hl=fr&q=cockpit%20%22spawning%20remote%20bridge%20failed%20with%200%20status%22
- As a workaround, I will continue to use my "with a password" user, but this would force me to let the 9090 port opened while a local client would have been fine.

Hoping my problem would avoid others to loose their time trying to fix their servers, the **issue comes from Ubuntu's Cockpit** and maybe, someone would be able to help me to fixe it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood what appends:

- On my local Ubuntu, I decided to use "su" and remove my user from the "sudo" group so I could set a weak password without too much security leak.
- Due to that, I locally logged to Cockpit as root to be "privileged" and able to add servers
- Logged as root, Cockpit tries to log as... root before asking a specific username for my newly added server and, as it's disabled by default on Debian, it answers `Please login as the user "debian" rather than the user "root".`. It was in the logs, one line above, but I didn't realized it was the answer of my server's SSH.

To fix it, I forgot my picky "not being myself sudoer", and do not connect to Cockpit as root anymore locally, thus Cockpit proposed me to choose a user and it worked perfectly specifying "debian" and my rsa key.

Cheers